# Highest in-sample R-squared

Tags: regression, r-squared

Which of the following model has the highest in-sample $R^2$ in the same dataset: OLS linear regression, lasso, or ridge?

My guess is OLS. Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you think the answer is OLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

All three are different techniques for estimating the coefficients in a multiple linear regression model. By definition, OLS chooses the coefficient values that minimise the residual sum of squares, $\mathrm{RSS}=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$. This is equivalent to maximising the in-sample $R^2$ coefficient, as this is equal to $1-\mathrm{RSS}/\mathrm{TSS}$, where the total sum of squares $\mathrm{TSS}=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$ doesn't depend on the coefficients.